# Generate Date with Day (1-7/Mon-Sun), Week Of Month (1-5), Month (1-12) in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have below Data in DataBase,

```
Day Number   --> 1 to 7 (Representing Monday to Sunday)

Week Number  --> 1 to 5 (Representing Week Number of Month)

Month Number --> 1 to 12 (Representing Jan to Dec)

Year         --> Can be this year future year
```

In PHP I need to generate corresponding `date (YYYY-MM-DD)` with above data.

Comment: Yes. Below is one example.

Day Number : 6 --> Saturday
Week Number : 2
Month Number : 9 --> September
Year --> 2020


So the result i need is 2020-09-12

In other words need to get the date of Second week Saturday of September 2020.

Comment: Do you need a string or a date object as result?

Comment: Anything is fine.. String or Date Object.

Comment: Perfect, what database do you use? MySQL, Oracle, MS? How do you extract data from database?

Comment: I think i can use echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("second saturday of september $currentYear"));

Let me try with my DB data.

Comment: With `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("second saturday of september $currentYear"));` you will get `2020-09-12` but you are not retrieving it from your DB

Comment: Yes. That is correct. I am planning to have custom function in PHP to convert the data.

BTW, Is there any simple way ?

My DB is in MySQL. I am extracting data from table with group_concat, Then converting the CSV to array in PHP.

Comment: Oks, but what database do you use?

Comment: ```+-------+-------+--------+
| days  | weeks | months |
+-------+-------+--------+
| 3,4,6 | 3,5   | 6,12,9 |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

This is my output from DB.

Comment: Ok, so you should have something like `mysql_query($conn,'SELECT days, weeks, months from table);` and then an assoc method with loop `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))`. Correct? Update your question with DB retrieving's script

Comment: With my solution now i am facing the PHP's +1 Month issue... 5th Week Saturday of September 2020 is actually not exist. But PHP selecting 2020 October 3rd as the 5th Week Saturday of September 2020.

Comment: Add all the code please

Comment: Not able to paste full code here in comments, due to character count restriction.

Comment: Just paste the extraction from query and the loop of records.

Comment: Please see in this file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fJG2xDX0h4_zChvJl1gfgaUwLahUqbBV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'll check as soon as possible

Comment: Got time to check on this ?

Comment: Ok.. I have done few testing, the function is not perfect, having some issues. I will try to clear with some modification.

Comment: I cannot review your codes. Please add only the extraction's code in your answer (just 10 lines are enough) or your answer'll be closed (required more details)

Comment: I didn't get what you are looking for. My extraction is something i have attached in above. Instead of using nested loops i have done it another way and that is why it is lengthy. 

It is NOT full application code. Just only the conversion of day,week,month to a date.

Comment: In your question there is no code about how you get data from database. Let us know the variables where you store data.

Comment: That actually i had included in my attachment.
The Data Will be in variable ```$CI_POLICY```. ```This will be an array``` which have the data ```like what i posted in my 5th Replay```. Then i am using explode to convert day,week,month to separate array.

```EG: $Days       = explode(",",$CI_POLICY[0]['days']);```

BTW, i have resolved by re-writting the code with foreach (Of course it is nested loops, so not sure about the drawbacks).

Now only outstanding issue is, the week starting from Monday instead of Sunday in PHP.  Do you have any suggestion to change to start from Sunday always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written below functions for achieving it. And it working fine with initial tests.

````
$Day_Config = array(
    1 => 'Monday',
    2 => 'Tuesday',
    3 => 'Wednesday',
    4 => 'Thursday',
    5 => 'Friday',
    6 => 'Saturday',
    7 => 'Sunday'
  );

$Week_Config = array(
      1 => 'first',
      2 => 'second',
      3 => 'third',
      4 => 'fourth',
      5 => 'fifth',
    );

  function weekOfMonth($date) {
    #Get the first day of the month.
    $firstOfMonth = strtotime(date("Y-m-01", strtotime($date)));

    #Apply formula.
    return intval(date("W", strtotime($date))) - intval(date("W", $firstOfMonth)) + 1;
  }
  
  function getDateFromText ($year,$month,$week,$day) {
    global $Day_Config;
    global $Week_Config;
    
    $txtFormat  = $Week_Config["$week"]." ".strtolower($Day_Config["$day"])." of ".date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10))." ".$year;
    $DateFromTtxt       = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$txtFormat"));

    return $DateFromTtxt;
  }

function getNextRuntime ($day,$week,$month,$time) {
    #Get Current Day Details
    $Year       = date("Y");
    $thisMonth  = date("n");
    $thisWeek   = weekOfMonth(date("Y-m-d"));
    $thisDay    = date('N');

    #Get Received Data From DB
    $Days       = explode(",",$day);
    $Weeks      = explode(",",$week);
    $Months     = explode(",",$month);

    #Loop Through Months
    foreach ($Months as $Value_Month){
      if($Value_Month >= $thisMonth){
        #Loop Through Weeks
        foreach ($Weeks as $Value_Week){
          if($Value_Month == $thisMonth){
            if($Value_Week >= $thisWeek){
              #Loop Through Days
              foreach ($Days as $Value_Day){
                if($Value_Month == $thisMonth && $Value_Week == $thisWeek){
                  if($Value_Day >= $thisDay){
                    if($Value_Day == $thisDay && $time > date('H:i:00')){
                      return getDateFromText($Year, $Value_Month, $Value_Week, $Value_Day);
                    } elseif ($Value_Day != $thisDay) {
                      $Result       = getDateFromText($Year, $Value_Month, $Value_Week, $Value_Day);
                      $Result_Month = date('n', strtotime($Result));
                      if($Result_Month == $Value_Month){
                        return $Result;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                } else {
                  $Result       = getDateFromText($Year, $Value_Month, $Value_Week, $Value_Day);
                  $Result_Month = date('n', strtotime($Result));
                  if($Result_Month == $Value_Month){
                    return $Result;
                  } else {
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }  
            }
          } else {
            foreach ($Days as $Value_Day){
              $Result       = getDateFromText($Year, $Value_Month, $Value_Week, $Value_Day);
              $Result_Month = date('n', strtotime($Result));
              if($Result_Month == $Value_Month){
                return $Result;
              } else {
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    #Select Next Year If Current Year Not Provided Any Date
    ++$Year;
    foreach ($Months as $Value_Month){
      foreach ($Weeks as $Value_Week){
        foreach ($Days as $Value_Day){
          $Result       = getDateFromText($Year, $Value_Month, $Value_Week, $Value_Day);
          $Result_Month = date('n', strtotime($Result));
          if($Result_Month == $Value_Month){
       
            return $Result;
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

#Testing Functions
$day     = '2,5,7';
$week    = '2,5';
$month   = '9,10';
$time    = '10:00:00';

echo getNextRuntime ($day,$week,$month,$time)

#Output

If you are running it on 13th September 2020 before 10:00 AM, then the output will be as below

```2020-09-13```
````

Comment: Add what do you want as output

Comment: Added Sample Output.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a date made by `$day`, `$month` and `year`, to get "next {weekday}" such as "next saturday" you can use this way:

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("next saturday",strtotime("$month/$day/$year")));
```

Be careful, in some cases dates like `02/09` and `09/02` are both plausible so you may have problems depending on what `strtotime` understands.

You can replace "next saturday" with some other nice stuff, examples:

```
strtotime("now");
strtotime("10 September 2000");
strtotime("+1 day");
strtotime("+1 week");
strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds");
strtotime("next Thursday");
strtotime("last Monday");
```

More info here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: I don't think this will be useful in my case, as i have another important data for week number.

The date should be generated based on Day Number (1-7), Week Number (1-5), Month Number (1-12).

EG:-

``` Day - 7
    Week - 2
    Month -9```

Output Should be : ```2020-09-13```

Comment: BTW, do you have any suggestion to start PHP internal calendar system from Sunday ? or date or strtotime count from sunday ?

Comment: Use `$thisDay    = date('w');` instead of `$thisDay    = date('N');`. 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday. If you want to start with 1 as Sunday just add `+ 1`